# before action method not working after add exception in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

af first i'm newbie in rails . I have project witch have multiple controller , i added new method to my cotroller to get my logs but after that rails server display 401 error .
this is my authentiocation

```rb
before_action :authenticate_staff, except: %i[webhook public_track tracking_hook]
```

and this is my method

```rb
def tracking_hook
  byebug
  Rails.logger.info 'Controller: Tracking, Action: tracking, role: customer, ' \
                    "barcodeId #{tracking_params['barcode']}, message: start request"
  ::TrackingHookWorker.perform_async(tracking_params)
  Rails.logger.info 'Controller: Tracking, Action: tracking, role: customer, ' \
                    "barcodeId #{tracking_params['barcode']}, message: end request"
  render json: {success: true}
rescue StandardError => e
  byebug
  Rails.logger.error('Controller: Tracking, Action: tracking, role: customer, ' \
                          "barcodeId #{tracking_params['barcode']}, message: " + e.to_s)
  render json: {success: true}

end
```

my problem is befor i added this method to my project every thing is fine but after that it gaves me error 401 , i use byebug and find if i change before action method to

```rb
skip_before_action :authenticate_staff, only: %i[webhook public_track tracking_hook]
```

everything goes fine . I can't understand what happen to my project and what should i do ?
sorry for my terrible english.

Comment: before_action except: and skip_before_action only: both are the same in the execution, can you show us an error?

Comment: i use postman to check my api but when i use before action postman  says you are un authorize but when i use skip_before_Action it turn my result , i cant understand what happen because before i added this method (before action) work well but after that it's said i am unauthorized